# best geometry software program for beginners

Tags: geometry, math-software

Here is what I am looking for in a geometry program since I only know the basics of geometry and coding:

does not have coding(or little)

focused on geometry

allows for labeling  numbers and words

isn't complicated

more on the beginner side (but not nec a beginner app)

nice pres 
allows you to draw shapes 
control the length of your shapes and lines 
no money (or little, some )

Comment: Use the freeware Geogebra.

Answer (score 7):

Consider geogebra: https://www.geogebra.org/

(I think a link only answer is OK for this question.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, in my opinion this is powerful and easy to use.
http://car.rene-grothmann.de/doc_en/

Answer (score 0):

Try this website, it might help. https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/
 or this  http://www.cabri.com/